# I edited the local.xml file so please help to find mistake

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-connect, local.xml

I installed some extensions and that required to edit the local.xml. Then the extension messed up my top nav bar so I had to uninstall it. Now I have no extension, No nav bar and my local.xml is messed up. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/skin.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
    <reference name="header"><remove name="top.links" /></reference>
    <?php echo getChildHtml('top.links') ?>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links.custom">
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action>
            </block>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>130</position></action>
            <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link"/>
            <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
        </reference>

       <reference name="right">
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_right_info_block" before="-">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>right_info_block</block_id></action>
            </block>
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_left_info_block" after="left.poll">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>left_info_block</block_id></action>
            </block>
            <remove name="right.newsletter" />
        <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
    </reference>

        <reference name="header">
            <block type="cms/block" name="quick-access-links">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>quick-access-links</block_id></action>
            </block>
            <block type="cms/block" name="header_phone_block" before="quick-access-links">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>header_phone_block</block_id></action>
            </block>
            <block type="cms/block" name="search_block_content" before="">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>search_block_content</block_id></action>
            </block>
        <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher_header" as="store_switcher_header" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <!--<remove name="top.links" />-->
        </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer">
            <remove name="store_switcher" />
        </reference>

        <!--Begin cart top-bar -->
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar_top" template="checkout/cart/sidebar-top.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <!--End cart top-bar -->
    </default>
    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links.custom">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>

    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links.custom">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Register</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/><title>Register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>120</position></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_out>
</layout>
```

Comment: Always save an original copy before editing. If you have sequential copies of the changes, it's easy to use the differential compare tool in a programming text editor like Textpad to hunt down and fix the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issue in local.xml file

**1)** The `toplink` render php is `included`.It need to `remove` because php code is not executed in xml file.

Just remove

```
<?php echo getChildHtml('top.links') ?>
```

**2)** switch store is block is close two wise:

So,     change from

```
 <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher_header" as="store_switcher_header" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <!--<remove name="top.links" />-->
        </block>
```

To

```
<block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher_header" as="store_switcher_header" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
    <!--<remove name="top.links" />-->
<!-- </block> -->
```

Comment: show two local xmls filles